# Display charts according to month selected by user from JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, charts

I am having a json file (data.json) and HTML file which contains one select menu and button on selecting of month the chart should display fetching value from json file currently the chart is displayed on hard coded value but I want dynamic values instead so please suggest ways to do it.

Here is the plunkr link [code](https://plnkr.co/edit/otFp7Qt7JjUuQ1miwVhA?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>

<script src="data.json"></script>

<script>

function func()
{
var z=document.getElementById('month').value;


alert(mydata);



        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
            title: {
                text: "Sales Report"+z,
                fontFamily: "Verdana",
                fontColor: "Peru",
                fontSize: 28

            },
            animationEnabled: true,
            axisY: {
                tickThickness: 0,
                lineThickness: 0,
                valueFormatString: " ",
                gridThickness: 0                    
            },
            axisX: {
                tickThickness: 0,
                lineThickness: 0,
                labelFontSize: 18,
                labelFontColor: "Peru"

            },
            data: [
            {
                indexLabelFontSize: 26,
                toolTipContent: "<span style='\"'color: {color};'\"'><strong>{indexLabel}</strong></span><span style='\"'font-size: 20px; color:peru '\"'><strong>{y}</strong></span>",

                indexLabelPlacement: "inside",
                indexLabelFontColor: "white",
                indexLabelFontWeight: 600,
                indexLabelFontFamily: "Verdana",
                color: "#62C9C3",
                type: "bar",
                dataPoints: [
                    { y: mydata.January[1].count, label: "21%", indexLabel: "Video" },
                    { y: 25, label: "25%", indexLabel: "Dining" },
                    { y: 73, label: "33%", indexLabel: "Entertainment" },
                    { y: 36, label: "36%", indexLabel: "News" },
                    { y: 42, label: "42%", indexLabel: "Music" },
                    { y: 60, label: "49%", indexLabel: "Social Networking" },
                    { y: 50, label: "50%", indexLabel: "Maps/ Search" },
                    { y: 55, label: "55%", indexLabel: "Weather" },
                    { y: 61, label: "61%", indexLabel: "Games" }


                ]
            }
            ]
        });

        chart.render();


}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/canvasjs/1.7.0/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>  
<div>
    <span>
        <select id='month'>
            <option selected value='January'>January</option>
    <option value='February'>February</option>
    <option value='March'>March</option>
    <option value='April'>April</option>
    <option value='May'>May</option>
    <option value='June'>June</option>
    <option value='July'>July</option>
    <option value='August'>August</option>
    <option value='September'>September</option>
    <option value='October'>October</option>
    <option value='November'>November</option>
    <option value='December'>December</option>
        </select>
    </span>
    <span><input type="submit" id="reportbtn" value="Report" onclick="func()"/></span>
</div>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I am using canvasjs for chart to display

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing the same thing using Google charts:

- Select month dropdown
- Press submit button
- Pass java script / jquery values to server through AJAX
- Write DB query according to month wise data you want
  For e.g. data values should be group by months
  ** It depends according to your requirement, this is just an example.

  ```
  +------------+------+
  |   month    |value |
  +------------+------+
  |  January   |  11  |
  |  February  |  22  |
  +------------+------+
  ```
- Execute DB query
- Get output in multi-dimension array
  For e.g. using PHP -> $table[] = array(months, values);
- JSON encode output rows from server
  For e.g. echo json_encode($table);
- Give AJAX response data back to client side chart
- Render the data in chart accordingly

Comment: my issue is how to get data in multi dimension array according to month

Comment: Well, you need to file separate question to get DB multi dimension array values according to your requirement. Please do research on SQL for that and get values first.